# I overfilled my honda edger with to much oil,

Tags: engine

It started, then oil started coming out of the air filter, the engine died, now it want crank over
I drained alot of the oil and it did have air in it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a two stroke engine? If so, small 2-strokes don't usually have oil in the crankcase? You run oil in the gas, which lubricates everything.

Comment: Pull the spark plug and spin it over, see how much oil squirts out.